# How to access script from multiple Game Objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know how to access scripts but not sure how to access scripts from different game objects? Example:

I have 1 vehicle named "Vehicle1" and code:

```
CarScript driveScript;

driveScript = GameObject.Find ("Vehicle1").GetComponent<CarScript > ();
```

This way I'm accessing CarScript from Vehicle1, but how do I access it with the same script but if name of the other car is "Vehicle2"? I know that since Unity 5 this is one way to do so, but not sure how to access script if there are multiple objects to access from.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: *"but how do I access it with the same script but if name of the other car is "Vehicle2""*?  `GameObject.Find ("Vehicle2").GetComponent`??

Comment: @Programmer I was talking about accessing both vehicles, not just one...

Answer (score 0):

So you want `Vehicle1` to check `isDriving` on `Vehicle2`?  Does `Vehicle1` have a reference to the `GameObject` for `Vehicle2`?  If so, you can just create a script variable and get a reference to it from `Vehicle2's GameObject`

```
scriptName vehicle2Script = vehicle2Obj.GetComponent<scriptName>();

if (vehcile2Script.isDriving).........
```

`scriptName` is the name of the script which contains `isDriving`

`vehicle2Obj` is a reference to the `GameObject` for `vehicle2`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to access different `GameObjects` that all have the same component, but do something different if they're named differently?

If that's the case, try this:

```
 CarScript[] carScripts = FindObjectsOfType<CarScript>();

 foreach(CarScript carScript in carScripts)
 {
     if(carScript.gameObject.name == "Vehicle1")
         print("I am vehicle 1!")

     if(carScript.gameObject.name == "Vehicle2")
         print("I am vehicle 2!") 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get many similar objects and use something looks like `GameObject.Find()` you need to use `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag()`.
So you will have tag "Vehicle" and many objects with different names must be with selected tag "Vehicle".

```
var vehicles = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Vehicle");
foreach(var vehicle in vehicles)
{
    vehicle.GetComponent<CarScript>();
}
```